# Is there a way to blacklist a UDP port? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, networking

My on-board NIC intercepts all UDP packets on port 623 before they can reach the driver(Intel AMT/ME). It creates problem with certain app that randomly picks a port for communication (via bindresvport()).

Is there a way to explicitly 'blacklist' a port in Windows 7? (so that related functions ignore it).

Obvious way is to create a simple app that bind to that port and simply sits in memory doing nothing. I'd like to find a better solution.

Comment: UDP\623 is IMPI, a protocol for accessing a visual terminal session with remote hardware, and is (at least in my experience) processed via circuitry on the motherboard. For that reason, the Windows kernel is not involved in the communication at all (in fact the primary reason to use iLo or IMPI is so you can access the BIOS/firmware configuration tools when windows isn't booted). As such, the best bet is to disable impi in the bios, and if that doesn't do it, you will have to filter upstream before it reaches your hardware.

Comment: @Frank Thomas Yes, this is exactly what happens. Problem is that software tries to use this port without realizing it is being intercepted -- this leads to (originally mysterious) problems I have to deal with at random points in time. Looking for a way to mark this port as unusable...